# UIScrollview not working in ipads

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I am using xcode 6.4. I am trying to make a sign up page inside a `UIScrollview` with `wAny hAny` autolayout format. The page is scrolling fine in all iPhone devices both in landscape and potrait mode. But in iPads the page is not working fine. The signup page is not covering all parts of the Scrollview. What will be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your page is not covering all parts, usually your scrollview will scroll when it is a little bigger then the width or height. Try to increase the UIScrollView frame size programatically if you cannot do that using the Interface Builder.